# Fastest regex for first occurence of a word

Tags: c#, regex

I would like my regex to capture the following kind of strings as two Urls with `"%3f"` inside them.

```
https://*****%3f****%3D,https://*****%3f****%3D …
```

Where each string URL of this type should be captured by itself. Note - The `*` is here for simplification and the URLS can be in any part of the big string with anything in between.

My regex now is:

```
(https://\S+?%3f)(?<toDelete>\S+?%3D)
```

But I've been asked to see if there's a non lazy approach for this (or just a faster version), as it is much slower then greediness, and this regex will be called over huge strings and dataflow.
Note that the reason I cant simply put `\S*` is that doing so will capture in one match from the first `http` to the last `%3D`.

Comment: Why not split with comma and then get substrings before `%3f`? If you want to use regex, why capture what is after `%3f`? Just use `https://\S*?%3f`. Or - if you want a superefficient regex - `https://[^%\s]*(?:%(?!3f)[^%\s]*)*%3f`

Comment: Just to be sure can you show your desired output? Don't assume regex is the fastest way, I'm pretty sure as @WiktorStribiżew alludes to String.Split will probably outperform a regex here.

Comment: its not always separated by commas, it can be in any part of my strings.
and as my regex suggests I want to delete the part after the %3f so I need to capture it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might probably split the string with a comma and then get a substring up to the `%3f` value.

If you want to make the `\S*?` pattern work "faster" you must take into account what kind of context this part of a pattern should be aware of.

You are matching any char that is not a whitespace char, any amount of times, up to the first occurrence of `%3f`. That is, you want to match any chars other than `%` and whitespace *or* `%` chars that are not followed with `3f`. That makes `(?:[^\s%]|%(?!3f))*`. However, alternation ruins the whole idea of optimization. You need to use the "unroll-the-loop" approach: `[^%\s]*(?:%(?!3f)[^%\s]*)*`.

So, the whole pattern will look like

```
https://[^%\s]*(?:%(?!3f)[^%\s]*)*%3f
```

Or with the `Delete` part:

```
(https://[^%\s]*(?:%(?!3f)[^%\s]*)*%3f)(?<toDelete>[^%\s]*(?:%(?!3D)[^%\s]*)*%3D)
```

For short strings, this last pattern might work a tiny bit slower than the `\S+?` based pattern, but it becomes much more efficient when the matched string becomes longer.

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: @OhadBitton Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you